# Temporary alias a cmd to squash an existing command, then expire upon script exit

Tags: node.js, bash, unix, alias

Suppose the command `bam` is on my system.  Let's refer to it as bam1.
Suppose that that I have another version of the `bam` binary on my system (bam2, although it may be named something much different).

When I run `some-script`, I want in that script (and all child processes) for all calls to `bam` to to use bam2. They will otherwise use bam1, as bam1 is in the $PATH by default for that environment.

Assume that I have the full path to bam2 available.
Assume that `bam` may run child processes that *also* call `bam`
Assume that if anything goes wrong, `bam` *must* revert back to bam1.
Assume unix-ish systems for now, but Windows support welcome.

```
$ alias bam="bam2" && bam # <== doesn't quite work. see ls test below
$ alias bam="ls" && ls # <== "-bash: bam: command not found"
```

I need to override an application binary pointer with another one temporarily.  The usage intent is for a nodejs application, so something I can do in there that would perform better x-platform in a node context would be great.

I considered making a tmp symlink and prepending its folder to the system PATH, but I have a feeling there may be a simpler way.

Any tips?

Comment: Why can't you just use the full path of the binary?

Comment: great question @PSkocik, the missing detail is that child processes will call `bam`, and I must have them temporarily using bam2.  Thanks for asking.  I will clarify in the question

Comment: Aliases don't work in bash scripts unless you turn them on with `shopt -s expand_aliases`, but functions do the job just as well or possibly better.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you'll spawn a process that'll try to run `bam` and you can't make the child process use the full path?

Comment: @PSkocik, right.  The child processes are generally pulled from the user ecosystem.  In actuality, I'm running `node some-build-script.js` (using a binary that likely is _not_ the system binary).  This script then may run some user scripts that call `node some-user-build-script.js`.  I need that second `node` call to be using the same, non-sys binary that I used to ensure that native addons get compiled properly.

Comment: By "anything goes wrong", I assume you just mean `bam2` couldn't be found?

Comment: My actual intent is that no matter how the script exits (exit code 0, error code, or anything else), it needs to appear as though my script had never   modified the environment

Comment: The binary is named differently, so the desired squashing would not occur

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a temporary directory

```
 tmpdir=`mktemp -d`
```

mark it for removal on exit

```
 trap 'rm -rf "$tmpdir"' exit
```

add it to your PATH:

```
 PATH="$tmpdir:$PATH" #<= This is the key part
```

and then place a link named after your override inside of `$tmpdir`

```
 ln -s "$(which bam2)" "$tmpdir"/bam
```

Any processes you spawn from here will inherit the `PATH` variable (it's an environment (=exported) variable) and if they attempt to search for an executable, your temporary directory is what they'll search first.

If you're concerned about security, you'll want to make it (a possibly permanent) read-only directory instead of a temporary, writable one.

Comment: thanks @PSkocik.  I may try something similar to this!  Would you be willing to comment on this? https://gist.github.com/cdaringe/d76b90a8a4522a4d8d02

Comment: @cdaringe You want a symbolic link to `"$(which ls)"` (`which` should give you `/bin/ls`, pun intended). A symbolic link to `ls` will look for `ls` in the directory the the link is placed in and that's it (no PATH search, no `PWD` taken into account).